# How to set multiline title v-toolbar in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, title, multiline, card

I'm creating app in Vue.js with Vuetify library. In app I am dispalaying v-cards, whose titles are of different length. My problem is that I want to display the all title in as many lines as needed. Instead, the title breaks off and there are "..." and only one line. How to change it?

Template:

```html
<v-card max-width="900" class="mb-6">
  <v-toolbar flat color="grey darken-2" dark>
    <v-toolbar-title align="left">
      {{ labels[0].key }}
    </v-toolbar-title>
  </v-toolbar>
  <v-card-text>
    <v-text-field
      color="grey"
      v-model="labels[0].translation"
      label="Translation"
    >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

[image]

After using:

```
style="overflow: visible"
```

[image]

All text is displayed but still not multiline.

Edit:

After using `p`  instead of `v-toolbar-title`:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the default syles of toolbar?

Comment: Does `overflow-wrap: break-word;` work?

Comment: @painotpi it does not work

Comment: @Bülent Akgül I don't see anything about it in the documentation

Comment: @Weronika could you share the css as well? If you could replicate your example on codesandbox, that would be helpful.

Comment: You don't need documantation. Check the styles in the dev tool and see which styles create that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be better off not using the toolbar at all in this case - it's been designed to have a set of fixed heights (that's why it has the short, prominent and extended prop). You have multiple alternative options, but this might be the easiest:

```
<v-card max-width="900" class="mb-6">
  <v-card-title color="grey darken-2 white--text">
      {{ labels[0].key }}
  </v-card-title>
  <v-card-text>
    <v-text-field
      color="grey"
      v-model="labels[0].translation"
      label="Translation"
    >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

If you specifically need the `dark` prop, you can wrap the title in a `v-sheet` instead:

```
<v-card max-width="900" class="mb-6">
  <v-sheet dark>
    <v-card-title>
      {{ labels[0].key }}
    </v-card-title>
  </v-sheet>
  <v-card-text>
    <v-text-field
      color="grey"
      v-model="labels[0].translation"
      label="Translation"
    >
    </v-text-field>
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

https://codepen.io/thomaskuhlmann/pen/rNyLXxL

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible ... I searched through Vuetify ... you can change it to ordinary `p` element not `v-toolbar-title`

Comment: Thank you, I'll use it. But you don't know how to adjust the height of toolbar to lines of `p`? I edited my question and put it a picture of what I mean.